# Reverting edits in Tksheet v.7

Tags: python

Does any of you have an experience with the following issue in Python's Tksheet v7: I'm asking to confirm the changes/edits in the table before saving them to the database (this is happening in the function that was bound to the "SheetModified" event). When receiving a "No" answer I want the sheet to display the old value. Currently it still displays the edited/new entry.

I receive the following error when I attempt to modify the cell's value back to the old value:

```
File "c:\Users\ruslan\Documents\PyInv\Interface\brWindow.py", line 19, in updateInv
    **self.frame.sheet["B" + str(x+1)].data = old_value**
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ruslan\Documents\PyInv\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tksheet\other_classes.py", line 138, in __setitem__
    self["widget"].set_data(self, data=item)
  File "C:\Users\ruslan\Documents\PyInv\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tksheet\sheet.py", line 1676, in set_data
    if emit_event is True or (emit_event is None and span.emit_event):
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ruslan\Documents\PyInv\.venv\Lib\site-packages\tksheet\other_classes.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'emit_event'
```

Code:

```
def open_brWindow(self):
    def updateInv(event):
        for (x, y), old_value in event.cells.table.items():
            if (x+1 < self.frame.sheet.get_total_rows()):
                if (y+1 == 2):
                    result = askyesno(title="Потвердите изменение брокера", message="Заменить наименование с " +
                                      old_value + " на " + self.frame.sheet["B" + str(x+1)].data)
                    if result:
                        Inv.updateInvName(
                            self.frame.sheet["A" + str(x+1)].data, self.frame.sheet["B" + str(x+1)].data)
                    else:
                        self.frame.sheet["B" + str(x+1)].data = old_value
                else:
                    result = askyesno(title="Подтвердите изменение инвестированной суммы",
                                      message="Заменить инвестированную сумму с " + str(old_value) + " на " + self.frame.sheet["C" + str(x+1)].data)
                    if result:
                        Inv.updateInvested(
                            self.frame.sheet["A" + str(x+1)].data, self.frame.sheet["C" + str(x+1)].data)
    cols = ("ID", "Брокер", "Инвестировано", "Общ затраты",
            "Общ стоимость", "Прибыль", "Активн", "Инвестир")
    self.frame.sheet = Sheet(self.frame, headers=cols)
    self.frame.sheet.default_column_width(width=5)
    self.frame.sheet.enable_bindings()
    self.frame.sheet.disable_bindings(
        "edit_header", "rc_insert_column", "rc_insert_row", "rc_delete_column", "rc_delete_row")
    # self.frame.sheet.popup_menu_add_command("Обновить данные", lambda:updateInv)
    # self.frame.sheet.popup_menu_add_command("Добавить брокера", lambda:addInv)
    self.frame.sheet["A"].readonly(readonly=True)
    self.frame.sheet["A"].bg = "yellow"
    self.frame.sheet["B:C"].readonly(readonly=False)
    self.frame.sheet["B:C"].bg = "lime green"
    self.frame.sheet["D:H"].readonly(readonly=True)
    self.frame.sheet["D:H"].bg = "yellow"
    self.frame.sheet.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=1)
    self.frame.sheet.bind("<<SheetModified>>", updateInv)
    for rw in InvView.getInvView():
        self.frame.sheet.insert_row(
            row=[rw.id, rw.invname, rw.invested, rw.totalcost, rw.totalvalue, rw.profit, rw.active, rw.invest])
    self.frame.sheet.insert_row()
    self.frame.btnAdd = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Добавить брокера", padx=10, command=lambda: addInv(
        self)).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=10)

    def addInv(self, event=None):
        row = self.frame.sheet.get_total_rows()
        Inv.addInv(self.frame.sheet["B" + str(row)].data,
                   self.frame.sheet["C" + str(row)].data)
```

When I try to use the set_data function (to avoid the "SheetModified" event) it doesn't work for me too.
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the generation of this error.